# "Pasting formed '__NSi_@', an invalid preporcessing token" error when add facebookSDK to my project

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm working on a project which is created last year.
Recently, i would like to integrated facebook SDK. 
However, when i add `FacebookSDK`, 
`#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` to `appdelegate.h` and build, it show errors in `ACACcountType.m` file:

```
"pasting formed "Pasting formed '__NSi_@', an invalid preporcessing token".
```

please see the screenshot here: [image]

I've studied and tried to change [C++ language dialect] and [C language dialect] in 
[build settings] --> [Apple LLVM 5.0] but nothing change. 
i'm got stuck here. Could you help me please. Many thanks.

Comment: make a screenshot of the error , and post it to some image sharing site and share link here

Comment: Thanks Kabira. i've just done. :)

Comment: you can still post a screenshot and answer the question yourself.. others could help from that in future

Comment: ah, i mean i've just uploaded the screenshot and add link in to my question. about the problem, it's still not resolved. :(

Comment: The fact that this is happening after the line declaring availability on iOS 7, but not after the ones declaring availability on iOS 6, makes me suspect that the compiler is using an older version of AvailabilityMacros.h. Are you sure you're using an iOS 7-compatible version of the Facebook SDK? Are you sure you don't have a custom version of any system header in your project? Have you tried to clean the project (cmd-K) before compiling again?

Comment: Thanks all for your helps. At last, i fixed my problems by creating new project with the same name, importing all the source from old project, then intergrating the Facebook SDK to new project --> it work. I guest that the reason is: my old project is created by Xcode 4, and there are some problems with the project config cause the bug.

Answer (score -1):

There has been a lot of changes to the Facebook SDK in the recent months, the new SDK does not require you to add anything to the Appdelegate.h, if you have downloaded them look at the sample apps and follow them:

in appdelegate.m you should have something like this (note there are more things that need to be added regarding FBsession control in the other parts of the app delegate) :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[FBProfilePictureView class];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UILocalNotification *localNotif =
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) {
     NSString *message =localNotif.alertBody; 
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:localNotif.alertAction
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];   

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
}




//facebook items deprecated  all items below are obsolete

/*
facebookController = [[QRSMFacebookVC alloc] init];
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:facebookController];
// Check and retrieve authorization information

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];}
facebookController.facebook = facebook;
facebookController.userPermissions = userPermissions;
  */  
  // Initialize user permissions
 //  userPermissions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
   // Override point for customization after application launch.

 self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;



}
  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Although the SDK attempts to refresh its access tokens when it makes API calls,
// it's a good practice to refresh the access token also when the app becomes active.
// This gives apps that seldom make api calls a higher chance of having a non expired
// access token.
[FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];

   }


 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
  {
    // if the app is going away, we close the session object
   [FBSession.activeSession close];
   }

  -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
         openURL:(NSURL *)url 
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
       annotation:(id)annotation {   

   BOOL ret = [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
   return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo.
i'm wrong to wrote "#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> to appdelegate.h". it's should be: "#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> to appdelegate.m".
anyway, i've check the sample prj from facebook. you still need to import sdk to use it. :)

Comment: check it out again until it works, I do not fully understand how this is happening my best guess is that UIKit has hooks into the FB SDK and this is what is causing your error. I worked on the app upgrade to the new SDK a few months ago,  my app works without any #import

Comment: My apologies  Hien, I put back the   --- #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

Comment: I did some testing in my own app and I put back the   ---    #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>  in the app delegate.h file to see if your error would appear. I also use the social and accounts.framework in my app (to access twitter) so logically the preprocess pasting error that you are getting should also hit my app - it does not  and it was working as it did before (so it does not matter if the FacebookSDK.h is in the h file or not).   I did have some difficulty putting the Facebook framework into the app, you maybe accessing the wrong or old version of the frameworks.